# What app is this chat icon from?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, chat

[image]Hi all,

I've been trying to identify what app this chat icon (outlined in red) is from. It's a screenshot from a Samsung phone in the USA. It's not the native Samsung or Google messages app. It has a right facing arrow inside of a speech bubble. I've tried googling but only come up with stock images for app developers. This is from a screenshot I received so I can't go into the phone and see what the notification is from. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: No, its not standard.  Only you know what apps you have installed.  Look at [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/189835/what-is-this-square-chat-bubble-balloon-icon-on-the-top-left-of-a-screen-it-h)

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. If you're the device owner, please try [the following method](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37443/44325). Otherwise, since there are millions of Android apps and more for notification icons, [the community can't help anymore in identifying a specific icon of an app](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2435/44325).

Comment: This isn't on my phone which is why I can't identify it myself. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @ferncorre Without the actual phone it would be very difficult/impossible to determine which app owns that icon. For all anyone knows it could be from an beta app not released to the public or the app isn't from the Google Play Store or its a side-loaded spoofing/hacking app downloaded by a victim